# Initializing object with custom YAML file in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml

I have a Spring Boot project with two YAML files in `resources` folder:

- `application.yml`
- `metrics.yml`

`metrics.yml` looks like this:

```
metrics:
    activeMetrics:
        -   type: TYPE_A
            value: 10
        -   type: TYPE_B
            value: 5
```

The class for it looks like this:

```
@Data
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("metrics")
public class ActiveMetrics {
    private final List<Metric> activeMetrics = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Main class is annotated with:

```
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource("classpath:/metrics.yml"),
        @PropertySource("classpath:/project.yml")
})
```

After application startup the `activeMetrics` list is empty, however, if I place the same config inside of `application.yml` the list initializes successfully.

`metrics.yml` is also loaded successfully, because when the path isn't right Spring Boot throws an exception.

How do I initialize this bean with second YAML file?

Comment: application.yml will over ride all this, Please try after removing application.yml OR $ java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/application,classpath:/metrics.properties

Comment: Is there any change after Spring Boot 2.0? I want some latest and easiest options as I think Spring Boot provides them!